# hdfs benchmark TestDFSIO not found

Tags: unix, hadoop, zsh

Im trying to run this command `hadoop jar hadoop-*test*.jar TestDFSIO -read -nrFiles 100 -fileSize 80MB -resFile /TestDFSIOwrite.txt`
But Im getting `zsh: no matches found: hadoop-*test*.jar`

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSbjq.png)

Im trying to measure performance of read and write on a standalone distribution

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying no files matching `hadoop-*test*.jar` are in your current directory.

For whatever documentation you're following, I assume that argument ought to be a literal file, without glob patterns